# how to write avr I2C master read function

Tags: c, embedded, avr, i2c, atmega

i have written some configuration function for ATmega168 to read data from TWI communication with DS1307. But i can write to DS1307 not read. Can someone help me.

this are my functions:

```
void TW_init(void)  
{
    TWBR = 2;
    TWSR = (1 << TWPS1);
    TWCR = (1 << TWEN);
}

void TW_start(void) 
{
    TWCR = (1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWSTA)|(1<<TWEN);
    while ((TWCR & (1<<TWINT)) == 0);
}

void TW_stop(void)
{
    TWCR = (1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWSTO)|(1<<TWEN);
}

void TW_write(uint8_t data)
{
    TWDR = data;
    TWCR = (1 << TWEN)|(1 << TWINT);
    while(!(TWCR & (1 << TWINT)));
}

uint8_t TW_read(void)
{
    TWCR = (1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWEN);
    while(!(TWCR & (1 << TWINT)));

    return TWDR;
}

uint8_t DS1307_Read(uint8_t address)
{

    unsigned short r_data;

    TW_start();
    TW_write(DS1307);
    TW_write(address);
    TW_start();
    TW_write(DS1307 + 1);
    r_data = TW_read();
    TW_stop();

    return r_data;

}

uint8_t DS1307_Write(uint8_t address, uint8_t w_data)
{
    TW_start();
    TW_write(DS1307);
    TW_write(address);
    TW_write(w_data);
    TW_stop();

}
```

I tried a lot to correct my configuration functions but i can't find a mistake or what is missing so maybe someone ales can help me with correcting it. I'm testing it in Proteus and it show me that clock has been set.

[image]

if more details needed I'll post them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `DS1307_Read()` you need to assert a "STOP" signal after selecting the address:

```
uint8_t DS1307_Read(uint8_t address)
{    
    unsigned short r_data;

    TW_start();
    TW_write(DS1307);
    TW_write(address);
    TW_stop();         // <-- STOP

    TW_start();
    TW_write(DS1307 + 1);
    r_data = TW_read();
    TW_stop();

    return r_data;
}
```

Since this is a DS1307 specific interface rather then generic I2C read, it would be more efficient to perform a sequential read/write of the entire time/date data as in [this example](http://www.exploreembedded.com/wiki/Real_Time_Clock(DS1307)_with_AVR)